Dynamically created Function is not calling or returning
I'm trying to dynamically create a Function in javaScript. Here is my code:
class Server {
   // Omitted for brevity
     public async method(method: Function, args: any[]) {
    const fsp = await import("fs/promises");
    const currentMethods: string[] = [];

    Object.keys(fsp).forEach((method) => {
      currentMethods.push(method);
    });

    Object.keys(fsp.default).forEach((method) => {
      currentMethods.push(method);
    });

    let matchedType = false;

    for (const currentMethod of currentMethods) {
      if (method.name === currentMethod) {
        matchedType = true;
      }
    }

    if (!matchedType) {
      throw new Error("Invalid method");
    }

    const callMethod = Function(
      `"use strict"; async () => {const {${method.name}} = await import("fs/promises"); return await ${method.name}(${JSON.stringify(args).replace("[", "").replace("]", "")});}`
    );

    const result = await callMethod();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
}

Usage:
const server = new Server();

await server.method(fsp.writeFile, ["temp.txt", "hello world"]);

The code works like this:

I pass the method I want to use in this case fsp(Node fs/promises).writeFile
Then I pass the args as an array
That generates the following code: "use strict"; async () => {const {writeFile} = await import("fs/promises"); return await writeFile("temp.txt","hello world");}
Then I call it and it should write the file

However, this does not work and does nothing. How can I fix it.

How can it work if it never runs?

Is this question dependent on node (e.g., fs/promises)? If so, please tag it as such. If not, please [edit] to make the code a [mre] that doesn't refer to it.

@innocent That is the problem. Thanks!

"I'm trying to dynamically create a Function" - why? What's the benefit over simply calling fsp.writeFile("temp.txt", "hello world") directly?

Because it I don't know what method I am calling. I could be calling fsp.readFile or fsp.exists ect...

@Ethan How do you not know that? You're passing it to server.method as the first argument! That whole server.method doesn't do anything useful, its call could be replaced by a direct call to the target function.

The question doesn't explain the purpose, but the whole solution is impractical. If the intention is to call some function with some arguments, it should've been just a callback, await method(() => fsp.writeFile("temp.txt", "hello world")). Or method(await fsp.writeFile(...)) or await method(fsp.writeFile(...)) if all that "method" does is instantly and unconditionally call fsp.writeFile. Same verbosity, less awkward api. Because providing a function just to get its "name" later, and restrict it to be fs function, and using eval for this is really awkward

There is no need to dynamically generate code for this type of situation and it is considered an anti-pattern to do so.  You can create a function that takes arguments about what to call or how to behave based on the arguments.  If you want to pass in a named method to call, you can do that to.

await callMethod(); could simply be replaced by await method(...args); for example.

I cannot pass this as a callback function due since the method is sent via a fetch request in string form. I think it would be far more impractical to send a whole node fs function over the network.

@Ethan String form? That's not what you've shown in your question, please update it. And still, you could just use fsp[methodName](...args), no need to eval/new Function any code.
